# Get result of async method

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I have method that does asynchronous call to web service. Something like that:

```
public static async Task<ReturnResultClass> GetBasicResponseAsync()
{
    var r = await SomeClass.StartAsyncOp();
    return await OtherClass.ProcessAsync(r);
}
```

And I want to provide synchronous alternative:

```
public static ReturnResultClass GetBasicResponse()
{
    return GetBasicResponseAsync().Result;
}
```

But it blocks on `Result` call. Because it is called on the same thread as a async operations. How can I get result synchronously ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right, if you're in a GUI application, the continuation part(s) of an `async` method will execute on the UI thread by default. And if you execute synchronous wait for the same Task on the UI thread at the same time, you will get a deadlock.

If it's your application, you can solve this by simply not waiting for the task synchronously.

If you're just writing a library, you can fix this by using [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This way, the continuation part of the method will not execute on the captured context (the UI thread in GUI applications), but instead on a ThreadPool thread.

```
public static async Task<ReturnResultClass> GetBasicResponseAsync()
{
    var r = await SomeClass.StartAsyncOp().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return await OtherClass.ProcessAsync(r).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Of course, the ideal solution is to not use synchronous operations in your GUI apps *and* use `ConfigureAwait()` in your library, so that others can use synchronous versions of the methods, if they want.

Comment: Thanks! Will `ConfigureAwait` affect async clients of my lib ? I mean, will async operations stay async, or they will be executed on other thread for all clients ?

Comment: Yes, it will affect async clients too, but in a way that should be okay. The async operations will stay async, it's just that the continuation part of the code that uses `ConfigureAwait()` won't execute on the UI thread. But any async code in methods that start on the UI thread will stay there (unless you use `ConfigureAwait()` there too).